# How to create a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am saving my data that I have extracted from different excel files in a CSV file here's the code :

```
import pandas as pd
def save_frames(frames, output_path):

        pd.DataFrame( data_mosul_df).to_csv
        output_path= r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt' 

        for frame in frames:
            frame.to_csv(output_path, mode='a', header=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
       frames = []
       save_frames(frames, r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt\datam.csv')
```

The problem is that the code is running, however, the CSV file is not created , anyone has an idea how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Please always consider adding a [mcve] and your input / output

Comment: there is no error... it's running but i don't see the CSV file in my folder, it's not created

Comment: Is it because of frames being an empty ilst?     frames = [ ]

Comment: are you sure that frames isn't empty? also make sure you already have a folder called tt.

Comment: @CalebMcNevin do you mean that i just need to put `frames =[pd.DataFrame( data_mosul_df).to_csv]` @cmxu the folder exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please also make sure that you already have this file in the specified path:

```
C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt\datam.csv
```

If the **file** (please check for file, not only for foldeR) is not present please create it in advance (append may not create the file for you).

**In your example frames is an empty list, please make sure that in your real code frames is populated correctly.**

I've added a quick debug print in order to help you finding out.

The following lines do not make 100% sense to me, so I removed them:

```
pd.DataFrame( data_mosul_df).to_csv
output_path= r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt'
```

Can you please explain what you were trying to do there so I can edit my answer in a more helpful way?

Please try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
def save_frames(frames, output_path):
        print("Frames content:")
        print(frames)
        for frame in frames:
            frame.to_csv(output_path, mode='a', header=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
       frames =[pd.DataFrame(data_mosul_df).to_csv]
       save_frames(frames, r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt\datam.csv')
```

Comment: You could use mode='a' and have the file already there, or you could use mode='a+' which will append or create the file if it doesn't already exist

Comment: @Pitto `pd.DataFrame( data_mosul_df).to_csv` Iis to define my Frame and `output_path= r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\tt'` is the folder is my output path where the file will be created , it already exists on my desktop thank you

Comment: If you don't assign pd.DataFrame( data_mosul_df).to_csv to a variable I don't think that the line is doing anything in your code. Why defining output_path two times (one in main, one in save_frames) without defining the file name the second time? Did you try my code? Is the file already existing on your desktop?

Comment: I've updated my code and answer after reading your newest comments. Please read the answer and try the code again (specifically check if the .csv file is in the right folder and already existing)

Answer (score 1):

You set

```
frames = []
```

so the for loop never executes, so no file is created.